# Implementing onSetInitialValue with null pointer exception in DialogPreference

Tags: android, kotlin, dialog-preference

I want to implement a TimePreference using DialogPreference, I found a good tutorial to do that [here](https://medium.com/@JakobUlbrich/building-a-settings-screen-for-android-part-3-ae9793fd31ec)
after implementing the TimePreference I noticed the onSetInitialValue(bool,Object) was deprecated and I implemented instead onSetInitialValue(Object)

When I try to implement onSetInitialValue(object) I'm getting a null pointer exception because defaultValue is null,
Although everything is working properly with the deprecated function

```
    fun setTime(time: Int) {

        mTime = time

        // Save to SharedPreference

        persistInt(time)

}


 //old version - works       

override fun onSetInitialValue(restorePersistedValue: Boolean, defaultValue: Any?) {

        setTime(

            if (restorePersistedValue)

                getPersistedInt(mTime)

            else

                defaultValue as Int

        )

    }

//New function doesn't work

    override fun onSetInitialValue(defaultValue: Any?) {

        setTime(

            if (mTime!=0)

                getPersistedInt(mTime)

            else

                defaultValue as Int

        )

    }
```